# Different resources from context.xml for maven profiles

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have an application running on a tomcat 8 which is working fine. Now I want to build the application for a development, a test and a production environment where the application connects to different database servers and I would like to select which resource to use by a maven property set in the different profiles.

So in my context.xml I have defined my data sources looking like this for each DB server.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/db-dev" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxTotal="1000" maxIdle="30"
    maxWaitMillis="10000" username="user" password="password"
    driverClassName="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mariadb://x.x.x.x:3306/dbname;" />

<Resource name="jdbc/db-test" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxTotal="1000" maxIdle="30"
    maxWaitMillis="10000" username="user" password="password"
    driverClassName="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mariadb://x.x.x.x:3306/dbname;" />
```

And in my web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>${db.context}</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

And in my pom.xml

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
        <db.context>jdbc/db-dev</db.context>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

And in Java

```
try {
    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup(ENV);
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/db"); // jdbc/db-??? is the issue
    return ds.getConnection();
} catch (NamingException e) {
    throw new SQLException(e);
}
```

And there's the problem, in Java I have a fixed string value pointing to only one resource. I know I could create a properties file during build, but for only that one value it seems a little to much. Is there a way to have the resource-ref point to different resources from the context xml while having only one reference name?

Another method I found was to have different resource files which I can include and exclude probably per profile, haven't got into it that much yet but maybe there is a far more easy solution which I just don't see right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to have the same binaries (i.e. WAR in this case) for every environments in order to follow "Build one, deploy often" CI/CD principle. The environment dependent configurations will then be [injected](https://www.aoe.com/techradar/methods-and-patterns/settings-injection.html) in some ways such as through environment variables ,JVM options when starting the application or external configuration file etc.

From [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/index.html) , Tomcat supports using `${xxxx}` for variable substitution in their configuration file :

> Tomcat configuration files are formatted as schemaless XML; elements
>   and attributes are case-sensitive. Apache Ant-style variable
>   substitution is supported; a system property with the name propname
>   may be used in a configuration file using the syntax ${propname}. All
>   system properties are available including those set using the -D
>   syntax, those automatically made available by the JVM and those
>   configured in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.

So, `context.xml` will probably looks likes:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/db" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxTotal="1000" maxIdle="30"
    maxWaitMillis="10000" username="${DB_USER}" password="${DB_PASSWORD}"
    driverClassName="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mariadb://${DB_HOST}/dbname;" />
```

Then configure `${DB_USER}` , `${DB_PASSWORD}` and `${DB_HOST}` as an environment variables or JVM options when starting tomcat etc....

Comment: Used maven properties/variables in the context.xml insteat of environment variables, works as well.